# Make div zoom in when zooming in on website

Tags: html, css

I want the div to zoom in when you zoom in on the website but I could not come up with a working solution. I don't want to use fixed dimensions (like 1920px x 1080px) because the the div should resize when resizing the browser window.

Example HTML:

```css
#container {
  background-color: crimson;
  width: calc(100vw - 30px);
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

The div always keeps in frame but I want it to (like with fixed px dimensions) grow and exceed the frame when zooming in

Comment: You can try using % value instead of absolute value, you can also try adding media query for better responsiveness.

Comment: But how can I make it fill the whole page using $ value? I tried setting height and width to 100% but then it's just as big as it's content.

Comment: You can try using media queries, they are used to make the web page responsive.